# Correct syntax for multiple execution lines inside an if-else Crystal Report formula

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports

I keep getting an error "A string is required here" in my Crystal Report formula. The part that gets highlighted is the "else" portion, suggesting that is where the error is. I've tried so many different variations of brackets, no brackets, semi-colons, etc... sometimes I get a different error but none of it seems to work.

```
Local stringVar outputString := ""; 
if isNull({Evaluation.Strategic}) then
(
 outputString := "None"
)
else
 (
stringVar array x := split({Evaluation.Strategic},"|"); 
Local numberVar i;
For i:=1 to Count(x) do
   (
   outputString := outputString + x[i] + Chr(10)
   )
);
outputString;
```

Can anyone please point out to me the correct syntax to do what I want to do? All the samples I've found online (there are few with multiple lines inside the if-else blocks) suggest this should work.

Thanks

Comment: Tried your code.. looks like `For loop` is not allowed inside `If`.. I have split the code when added for loop there was the error else every thing was fine.. May be other experts will be able to help you

Comment: Thanks for looking at it Siva. I think it is possible to have a 'For loop' inside the 'If', because the solution I ended up creating does just that. I'm still not sure why it didn't like the above code though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the below 2 sites I really thought you could have multiple statements inside an if-else but nothing I tried was working.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23735693/Multiple-line-IF-statement-in-Crystal-Reports.html

http://www.kenhamady.com/formulas/form08.shtml

I ended up getting this to work by restructuring my logic to be as shown below. It's a little clunky but it made the CR compiler happy.

```
//Syntactically correct - this worked:
//-------------------------------------
Local stringVar outputString := ""; 
stringVar array x := "";
Local numberVar i; 

If isNull({Evaluation.Strategic}) Then
   (
    x := ""
   )
Else
   (
    x := split({Evaluation.Strategic},"|");
   );

If x <> "" Then
(
    For i:=1 to Count(x) do
     (
     outputString := outputString + x[i] + Chr(10)
     )
)
else
(
For i:=1 to Count(x) do
     (
     outputString := "None";
     );
);

outputString;
```

Edited: And another site that suggests you can have more than one statement inside an If:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225356(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
IF ([enter first condition here] or [enter second condition here])
```

THEN ([enter first execution here]; [enter second execution here])
ELSE 0

worked for me (from links in the first answer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember your semi-colons at the end of each statement including the after the `if`

For instance this will not validate -

```
if (myCondition) Then (
    a:= "First"
    b:= "Second"
)

if (myOtherCondition) Then (
    a:= a + "Other First"
    b:= b + "Other Second"
)
```

However if you add the semi-colons Then it will validate -

```
if (myCondition) Then (
    a:= "First";
    b:= "Second";
);

if (myOtherCondition) Then (
    a:= a + "Other First";
    b:= b + "Other Second";
);
```

While Crystal does not need the semi-colon after the final statement within a the scope it is probably good practice to add it at the end of every statement as it will help avoid issues like this.